# How to fit a specific range of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

Let me explain my question by a toy example: Suppose I have a simple Gaussian function as follows:

```
test[x_] = 4*Exp[-(x)^2];
```

If I its data to a new Gaussian function I do:

```
data = Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 10/100}];

fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, 
   Method -> NMinimize];
fit[x]
(*3.99999994699 E^(-0.999999974954 x^2)*)
```

where I see it recovers the original function very good. Now I want to fit just a part of data, for example instead of {0 to 10} I want to pick data of {5 to 10} from original function and then fit them (so I think the center of gaussian is not 0 any more and it shifts +5 namely in exponent I have to write $(x+5)^2$ instead $x^2$, however I don't know what is the best way to implement it). How can I do this? Does Mathematica has a built-in function or option to do this?

Comment: Why do you think the center of the gaussian would shift, if you use only part of the data?

Comment: My mean was the center of fit function must be on x+5 to simulate that range of data of the original function, namely I must use $(x+5)^2$ in `fit` and also produce `data` from `5` to `10`

Comment: If you make a fit with only part of the data, the center and width will be approx. the same.

Comment: So how can I do a fitting by using just a part of data?

Comment: Are you looking to just generate data using the same function from 5 to 10:
data = Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 5, 10, 10/100}]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### **Edit: in this edited version I will try to be more concrete after the comments of the author of the OP. All detailed steps remain as they were presented in the first version at the end**

---

Breaking down the main point of the OP assuming that there is no miscommunication.

In the OP the author provided us with the following data

```
test[x_] = 4*Exp[-(x)^2];
data = Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 1/10}];
```

The task at hand is to choose the subset of the above data -already generated- in the region `{x,5,10}` and their corresponding `test[x]` values. This can be done programmatically in the following manner

```
data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]]
```

> [image: tab1]

So, as we see we sorted out the subset of the original data for which we have $x \geq 5$ and their corresponding `test[x]` values. Since we are done with this, we can this new set of data like so:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
   data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]], {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, 
   Method -> NMinimize];
fit[x]
```

> [image: fit]

We plot the specific set of data used for the fit and the fitted function we obtained for comparion

```
p1 = ListPlot[data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize /@ {Large}, PlotRange -> {All, All}];
p2 = Plot[
   2.6960551596217814` E^(-0.9843743450389705` x^2), {x, 5, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red}, PlotRange -> {All, All}];
Show[p1, p2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

> [image: ps]

---

### **Original answer: step-by-step explanation**

---

Comment: I think that the main point of this question is how to single out specific sublists from a mother list.

Also, I do not understand the reason of writing `10/100` and not `1/10`, so I am changing this to `1/10`

So, from the OP

```
test[x_] = 4*Exp[-(x)^2];
```

Now we generate the data

```
data = Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 1/10}];
```

How to single out the ones that `{x,5,10}` from the above list? I think that this is the question.

The following

```
data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]]
```

takes care of that. You get

> [image: tab1]

Another check for the validity of the above. If you want to single out data with `x=5` or higher you could have started by generating only those. I understand that this might not be useful for practical purposes, but serves well for a check.

```
lst = Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 5, 10, 1/10}];
```

and then

```
data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]] - lst
```

> [image: check]

Finally, doing the fit is easy now

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
   data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]], {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, 
   Method -> NMinimize];
fit[x]
```

> [image: fit]

Checking what we did

```
p1 = ListPlot[data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize /@ {Large}, PlotRange -> {All, All}];
p2 = Plot[
   2.6960551596217814` E^(-0.9843743450389705` x^2), {x, 5, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red}, PlotRange -> {All, All}];
Show[p1, p2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

> [image: ps]

Comment: Thanks, but you got my mean conversely! I exactly need to fit `{x,5,10}` data and as I understand you have done such a thing in your finally check, right?

Comment: @Wisdom So, I started by showing you how you can split the full data to the ones that start from `5` and higher programatically, then I did the fit for you and then I plotted the fit and the data. I don't understand what you mean when you say conversely to be honest. I thought that by breaking it down, it would help you understand the commands better.

Comment: @Wisdom if my answer and my comment did not clarify the situation, I am happy to try and re-organize my thoughts in an edited version. Please let me know :)

Comment: @Wisdom please see the updated version of my answer. From the data you generated, I sorted out only the ones for which we have $x \geq 5$ and their associated `test[x]` values and performed the `Fit` using this subset of the original data. I sorted out your data as there is no need to regenerate the `Table` as was suggested in the comment section by another user. Have a look and please let me know if it's clear now. If it's not clear, can you please leave a comment explaining which part is obscure to you? Many thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks you very much and so sorry for delay. I tried your method and seems works good. Just a more question: what is the general rule for picking a subset from a mother one? my mean is how to write `data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]]` for a general cases? Please explain about its components. for example if I pick a subset starting from 10 to 20 how to write it (provided the mother one is from 0 t0 20 also)? `data[[10*20 + 1 ;; All]]` ??

Comment: @Wisdom no need for apologies at all. So, the expression `data[[5*10 + 1 ;; All]]` is a pretty standard one; see for details the docs for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). An explanation is the following: you wanted to start from `5` and this is why the expression starts with `5`. The multiplication by `10` is because there was a step of `1/10`. The `+1` is because we started from zero. Please let me know if this comment clarifies the situation :)

Comment: Many thanks, so if I want to pick subset from 10 to 20 must write `data[[10*10 + 1 ;; All]]`??

Comment: @Wisdom Assuming that you would start from `0` and have a step of `1/10` then yes.

Comment: @Wisdom you can always check when you sort the set of mother data. For instance, this **generates** `Table[{x, test[x]}, {x, 10, 20, 1/10}]` the data you mentioned in the last comment, so you can compare this with `data[[10*10 + 1 ;; All]]` which is the set of **sorted** data :)